# Will/shall - I _____ never go there. With reason

Tags: deontic-vs-epistemic, shall-will

As like while teaching when such sentences come in front and we teach about using shall with I. Students come up with their books & guides to show as there is 'will' mentioned for answer this question.
Please help to teach well.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A relatively small subset of English speakers in Southern England in the 19th century and early 20th centuries, including the upper class, used *I shall* and *you/he/she/they will* as a default for future actions. The use of *I will* and *you/he/she/they shall* meant something beyond plain futurity, although the rules for exactly what it meant were fairly complicated.

See [this](https://www.bartleby.com/116/213.html) for an explanation of that system of tenses.

As far as I know, nobody uses this system anymore (except maybe some historical novelists). I suspect it was too complicated to survive for a long time. Let me note that in that system, your example

> I will never go there,

was a possible sentence; it was a much stronger statement than "I shall never go there."
It probably would have meant something like "I utterly refuse to go there."

In the U.S., we tend to use *will* for everything except first person questions and legal documents.

For first person questions, *shall we* is a suggestion, an offer, or asks for an opinion.<sup>1</sup> and *will we* is a question about facts. So you would generally say

> Shall we go to a movie?
>   Will we go to jail?

In the U.K., *shall* is used more often than in the U.S., but I don't know the current rules. BBC's Learning English seems to have a good explanation [here.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv43.shtml) Summarizing, it says that for statements, people use both *I/we will* and *I/we shall* in the first person, and that there is usually no difference in meaning; for first person questions, the same rules apply as in American English.

<sup>1</sup> Although lots of Americans don't even use *shall we* in these situations. They don't use *will we*, either. They might say something like *Do you want to ...*, *Do you think we should ...*

Answer (score -1):

**Shall** denotes a positive connotation with future actions, of course, this changes by each use case.

**Will** denotes a more negative connotation, associated with actions that the subject does not wish to happen.

Of course this changes for each usage, as English, being a modern language changes for each usage, so use whatever sounds best, and it will be fine.

(in this case, I think it depends on the class of the speaker, more upper class people would tend to use shall, and the lower classes would tend to use will).